# implementing Search bar cum Address Box in webview

Tags: android, webview, searchbar

I have a Webview along with an Edit Text Field as an Address bar, but the problem is , whenever i type in "http://www.google.co.in" the address bar just works fine but when i type in just "Google" , it doesn't work. below is my webview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText URLText;
Button GoButton;
WebView Browser;
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return true;
}
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    URLText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.URL);
    GoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Go);
    Browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebEngine);
    Browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");

     GoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
Browser.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
Browser.loadUrl("http://"+URLText.getText().toString());
}
});
}
}
```